# jQuery localScroll plugin doesn't works

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, scroll, scrollto

The localScroll plugin doesn't work for me. The console doesn't say anything and I don't see the error.

Here is my code:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-2.2.0.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.scrollTo.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.localScroll.js"></script>

<div id="navbar" class="collapse navbar-collapse">
  <ul id="navigation_menu" class="marginul nav navbar-nav">
    <li class="active"><a href="#mapa">Mapa</a></li>
    <li><a href="#institucional">Nosotros</a></li>
    <li><a href="#contacto">Contacto</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Then I have 3 sections with id and their content:

```
<section id="mapa" class="section_mapa"></section>
<section id="institucional" class="section_institucional fondoinstitucional"></section>
<section id="contacto" class="section_contacto">
```

My jQuery's code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).on("ready",function(){
      $("#navigation_menu").localScroll({

      duration:1000,

    });

  });
</script>
```

Please help me!

Thanks!

Comment: Did you add jquery to the page?  I see a couple of jquery plugins but I don't see jquery itself.

Comment: yes! Sorry. I put a short version of the code

Comment: also $(document).ready() might help and check if it gets there

Comment: I understand that it is the same but .ready() it is a function that includes "on" method, so, practically, it is the same no?

Comment: it seems that the nav and the html structure affects how this plugin works. try to isolate the html code for the plugin and check if it works

Comment: I isolate the html code and it isn't work :(. I don't understand which can be de error

Comment: try without the comma on `duration:1000,`

Comment: Your code works for me locally, after adding enough content to the sections to allow manual scrolling of the page. Do you have enough content? If so, what happens when you click on one of the links within `#navigation_menu` - do you get the standard anchor jump or is there no effect at all?

Comment: Yes i have the enough content. I'm using Bootstrap 3 and i think that is the problem. I'm trying to use ScrollSpy now

Comment: Ok, hope you can get that working. Just for what it's worth, I added in Bootstrap 3 (3.3.6) and didn't see any problems. So I think wherever the issue lies, it's not in your code example here.

Comment: Well I gave up. It works finally but in another html. I make it from 0. I don't explain why the other not works. Thanks a lot people!